# PopupWindow with GridView - Trouble with inflating view

Tags: android, gridview, popupwindow

I am having an issue while trying to use a GridView in a
PopupWindow.  On my Activity's onCreate method, I am inflating a
gridview from xml as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final GridView popupview = (GridView) inflater.inflate
(R.layout.gridviewpopup, null, false);
popupview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

would like this GridView to popup on a button click. Also inside of
my activity's onCreate, I have:

```
final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
 addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
 public void onClick(View v) {  
     PopupWindow mwindow = new PopupWindow(popupview, 100, 100);
     mwindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 100, 100);
     mwindow.setFocusable(true);  
            }  
 });
```

On button click, I am throwing a ClassCastException from
GridView.onMeasure(int, int).

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered adding the gridview to the Popupwindows main layout, and setting the setVisibility attribute to GONE? Then setting it to visible again when needed. This way you wouldn't have to worry about manually inflating the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the problem.  I was using the ImageAdapter code
form the Hello, Gallery example.  That contained a line of code
referencing a Gallary:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
```

When used with a GridView, this obviously causes a class cast
exception.

Now that I have my GridView displaying properly in a popupwindow, I am
having trouble capturing the OnItemClick event.  Below is my code.
OnItemClick is never being called when I make a selection in my
gridview in the popupwindow.  Any ideas?

```
final GridView gView = (GridView) grid_layout.findViewById
(R.id.gridview_layout);
gView.setWillNotDraw(false);
gView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
gView.setClickable(true);
gView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

final PopupWindow soundSelectorWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
soundSelectorWindow.setContentView(grid_layout);
soundSelectorWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
soundSelectorWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
soundSelectorWindow.setTouchable(true);

gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
long id)
      {
       //Never gets here.
       soundSelectorWindow.dismiss();
      }
 });
```